# Matching a specific HTML unordered list's items using PHP's regex

Tags: php, regex

Given a page with multiple unordered lists, how does one extract a single one's elements using a single PHP's regex?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A title</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="list1">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

How would one extract strings "Item 3" and "Item 4"?

Solution would be trivial if one first extracted all text inside `list2` - something like `<ul>.*?</ul>`, and then applied a second regex to extract contents of  various `<li>`s - something like `<li>.*?</li>` with `preg_match_all()`. Alternatively, one could use DOM.

However, for learning purposes, I'm interested how this would be one with a single regular expression.

Comment: All you will learn from trying to do this with regex is not to do this with regex.

Comment: you can use a tool like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this uses DOM parsing tools, because regex is not a good way to parse HTML files.

```
<?

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$lis = $xpath->query('//ul[@id="list2"]/li');

$text = array();

foreach ($lis as $li) {
    $text[] = $li->nodeValue;
}

var_export($text);

/*
array (
  0 => 'Item 3',
  1 => 'Item 4',
)
*/
```